# C - error: ignoring return value of scanf?

Tags: c

I'm only a few days into C programming, so I am not quite sure what's wrong with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int sides;
    printf("Please enter length of three sides :\n");
    scanf("%d", &sides);
    return 0;
}
```

The error message I receive is as follows:

> ignoring return value of scanf

What am I doing wrong here, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What do you intend to do? You haven't used the return value of `scanf` at all in this code! What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: While it is not strictly an error to ignore the return value of `scanf` and your compiler is just doing more hand-holding that you might expect, you should really *consider* it a programming (or at least a thinking) error to ignore the return value of any I/O operation. All I/O can fail, and a program that does not deal with that is essentially incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring return values in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888594/ignoring-return-values-in-c)

Answer (score 10):

You might code

```
if (scanf("%d", &sides) >0) {
    printf("you want %d sides.\n", sides);
} 
else printf("You did not enter any number.\n");
```

The [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) function (please follow the link) has several roles

1. it is expecting some input and could modify the variables you passed by address to it
2. it is returning the number of successfully input items

Comment: using an if statement works, I've done it before, but I don't encounter the need for an if statement on the uni computers... So perhaps its some setting on my home computer? ALSO thank you so for the link - it should prove handy

Comment: okay i got it working by calling it int sides = scanf("%d", &sides). thanks

Comment: No, coding `sides = scanf("%d", &sides);` is wrong. You should not use twice the same `sides` variable like this.

Answer (score 7):

It's a warning that stops your compiler from performing it's task (too strict settings). Check the return value of the scanf() function for errors and the warning should disappear.

> Return Value
>
> > On success, the function returns the number of items
> >     successfully read. This count can match the expected number of
> >     readings or fewer, even zero, if a matching failure happens. In the
> >     case of an input failure before any data could be successfully read,
> >     EOF is returned.

Comment: This is a warning btw and I don't have this problem using the computers at uni

Comment: There are several levels of strictness, one of them treats warnings as errors. I figured you meant that by `the error`.

Comment: sorry for not being specific, it is a warning that's being treated as an error

Comment: If you tell us your ide/compiler, we can provide you with information how to turn it off.

Comment: well i'm using gedit to write the programs and a standard xterm on ubuntu to compile/run

Comment: It's the `-Werror` flag, as @Thiruvalluvar pointed out. If you want to continue using it, you have to check the return values of functions.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` returns the number of "items", i.e. values passed both in the format string (a single item is e.g. `%d`, `%c` and so on), and in the subsequent arguments to `scanf`, for example, to read two integers separated by comma and space, you would use:

```
int x, y;
int items = scanf("%d, %d", &x, &y);
assert(items == 2);
```

I've already spoiled what my suggestion will be above - instead of adding unused variables, if you just want to read it, add an assertion:

```
#include <assert.h>
/* ... */
assert(scanf("%d", &sides) > 0);
/* ... */
```

Unfortunately, `assert(scanf("%d", &sides));` is not enough, because of EOF (this will return `-1`). It would be really elegant.

I think this is the way to go, if you don't want to continue your program with an uninitialized variable (`sides`) in this case.

Alternatively, you can capture `scanf`'s result to a variable, and handle it gracefully like in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't capture the return value of `scanf` in a variable.  It's a count (as an integer) of how many characters were read, so if that's important to you, then it may be good to capture it.

Comment: And it _is_ important to you, believe me. But it's a count of how many items were successfully scanned, _not_ characters.

Comment: Something as innocuous as `int count = scanf("%d", &sides);` is enough to stop the warning.  Although I will admit that on gcc 4.6, I'm not getting the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf()` function returns an integer value; if you are not planning to use it, you can just simply add `(void)` at the beginning of your `scanf` statement, like this:

```
    (void)scanf("%d", &sides);
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Although this is a valid answer, you *may* find that your suggestion is not well-received, here on Stack Overflow. There are numerous answers and comments emphasising the point that ignoring the returned value is generally not a good idea.

Comment: The person posing the question asked "What am I doing wrong here, and what can I do to fix it?". Their code indicates they are trying to read an integer. Unless they check the return value of the scanf() call, they have no idea if they have succeeded. That is something they are doing wrong. Your answer, while allowing the compilation to finish does not address this problem. So I do not see it as a helpful answer.