# C programming - sscanf for tkens separated by space

Tags: c, scanf, fgets, strtok

I'm currently trying writing a program using C (very new to C - only been learning it for 2 weeks), and I wanted to get a string of input from the user by stdin, in which the string has a char, followed by 2 floats (each has space in between). Example would be: "y 2.1 1.1".
My question is how can I obtain and store the 3 inputs, while making sure the first is a char, and the following two inputs are floats?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html Try `strtol`

Comment: It isn't possible for a user to enter something which isn't a char so any test if the first character is in fact a character will of course always return true. Do you mean how to check if it is in the character range `a-z`, or `A-Z`?

Comment: @Boku Why don't you use strtok()?

Comment: @SumeetSingh The main reason is probably I'm not really familiar with the strtok function. I've gotten it to work, but like I stated in the thread I could not get rid of the white spaces at the very end, and also I don't really know how to process the tokens - i.e. how to check what type they are and if they satisfy my requirements of first token being char, second and third being integers.

Comment: @Boku I have posted the solution, feel free for any queries.

Comment: @Boku The best explanation of strtok is given here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strtok.htm

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/36231014/2410359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I obtain and store the 3 inputs, while making sure the first is a char, and the following two inputs are ints?
>
> problem with this code is that there are extra spaces at the very end, and I don't know how to get rid of it.

A simple way to use `sscanf()` and check if there is extra *anything* after the scanned variable is to use `"%n"` to record the location of the scan at that point.

```
char in1;
int in2, in3;
int n = 0;
sscanf(array,"%c %d %d%n", &in1, &in2, &in3, &n);

if (n > 0 && (array[n] == '\n' || array[n] == '\0')) {
  Success(in1, in2, in3);
}
```

It is always important to check the results of `sscanf()`.  One way is to check its return value which should be 3 here.  Unfortunately that does not tell us if anything exist after `in3`.  By setting `n == 0` and then testing `n > 0`, code knows that scanning proceeded all the way successfully to `"%n"`.  Code can also test what character the scanning stopped at.

Comment: @Boku "this method fails" --> would be nice if you provided details.  Please provide 3: the value of `array[]`, `n` and the result of `strlen(array)`

Comment: @Boku Please provide the remaining 2: the value of `array[]` and the result of `strlen(array)`.  Suspect `array[5] == '\r'`

Comment: @Boku "array[5]= ascii code 13"  matches my "Suspect array[5] == '\r'" Given your post "But the problem with this code is that there are extra spaces at the very end, and I don't know how to get rid of it."  Try `"%c %d %d %n"`  (added space before %n).  This will pass any white-space after the number, be it `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `' '`.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with `sscanf()`, but don't forget to check its return value (look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/#return)). What really happens for input *"y 1u 1"* is that `sscanf` will read and store the `char`, which is valid, then it will read and store the `int` 1, which is valid, and then stop, because "u" does not match the format string.

Below is example code (using `scanf()` rather then `fgets()` and `sscanf()`).

```c
char in1;
int in2,in3;
int retval;

/*
char array[100] = {'\0'};
fgets(array, 100, stdin);
retval = sscanf(array, "%c %d %d", &in1, &in2, &in3);
*/
retval = scanf("%c %d %d", &in1, &in2, &in3);

printf("Scanned %d items\n", retval);

printf("Here they come: ");
if(retval > 0) {
    printf("%c ", in1);
}
if(retval > 1) {
    printf("%d ", in2);
}
if(retval > 2) {
    printf("%d", in3);
}
putchar('\n');
```

Comment: Then use `strtok()` to split the string into tokens and use `strtol()` where appropriate with end checking. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/#example) for inspiration.