# fgets not working properly , not accepting input

Tags: c, scanf, newline, fgets

I want to take input a string length of 80 but unfortunately it's skipping input.
Please suggest how to use fgets() properly, I followed various answer but still not working.
I also tried another method with publisher but no luck.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define title_max 80
#define publisher_max 20

typedef struct library_book
{
    int id;
    char title[title_max];
    char publisher[publisher_max];
    int code;
    union u
    {
        int no_of_copies;
        char month[10];
        int edition;
    }info;
    int cost;
}book;

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("\nPlease number of books: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    book books[n];
    char title[title_max];
    char publisher[publisher_max];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter the ID of the book: ");
        scanf("%d",&books[i].id);
        printf("\nPlease enter the title of the book: ");
        // scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&books[i].title);
        fgets (title,title_max,stdin);
        strcpy(books[i].title, title);
        printf("\nPlease enter the name of publisher: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&books[i].publisher);
        
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nTitle: %s",books[i].title);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output Console:

```
bright@goodman:/mnt/d/VS Code/C$ ./a.out

Please number of books: 1

Please enter the ID of the book: 1

Please enter the title of the book: 
Please enter the name of publisher: 123ewdfcads

Please eneter the cost of book: ''123

Please enter the code of the book: 
Title:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected repitition using fgets and sscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231014/unexpected-repitition-using-fgets-and-sscanf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after preceding call of `scanf`

```
    printf("\nPlease enter the ID of the book: ");
    scanf("%d",&books[i].id);
```

the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

So the next call of `fgets` reads in fact an empty string that contains the new line character from the input buffer.

```
    fgets (title,title_max,stdin);
```

You could use the commented call of `scanf` like

```
     scanf(" %79[^\n]", books[i].title);
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.

Also instead of the expression `&books[i].title` you need to use the expression `books[i].title`.

Otherwise before the call of `fgets` you could insert the following loop

```
while ( getchar() != '\n' );
```

to remove the new line character `'\n'` from the input buffer.